# Apply window commands to a subset of all windows?

Tags: vim

Suppose I wanted to move the top two windows (A and B) to a new column, like so:

```
+--------+  A
+--------+  B
+--------+  C
+--------+  D
+--------+  E
+--------+  F
+--------+
```

```
+---+---+
|A  |C  |
|   +---+
|   |D  |
+---+---+
|B  |E  |
|   +---+
|   |F  |
+---+---+
```

Is this possible in Vim, without closing and reopening files? I tried moving A and B each into their own columns, and then rotating them with `Ctrl-w r`, but Vim can't rotate more than two windows. Maybe there is a way to specify that I am focused on a rectangle containing exactly two windows?

Comment: You know there's a https://vi.stackexchange.com/, do you? There it might not get buried under hundreds of other questions.

Comment: It should be possible with vim.